# AppConfig.ready() is running before the migrations on manage.py test

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use Django's `AppConfig.ready()` method to run some some query on one of the models to retrieve some data.

I have the following code:

```py
class NewsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "apps.news"
    verbose_name = "News"

    def ready(self):
        NewsType = self.models.get("newstype")
        NewsType.names = NewsType.objects.values_list("name", flat=True)
```

then, on `urls.py` I'm using them as follow:

```
news_type_names_regex = generate_regex(NewsType.names)

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'news/' + news_type_names_regex, NewsModelViewSet, basename='news')
```

This works fine when the application runs (using uvicorn or runserver), but when running tests, the `AppConfig.ready()` gets executed before the migrations are run, which results in the following error:

```
...
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: news_newstype
```

I've read [the warning on the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready), but I don't think it is related to this issue. The reason why I'm doing this on the `AppConfig.ready()` is because it needs to be done somewhere after `django.setup()` but not in an async request context (as I'm using django channels and running the application ASGI).

Comment: How are you running your tests? Are you running some script that calls migrate before the tests? If so, post it here please.

Comment: No, I haven't any custom script. I think Django creates a new temporary database for tests.

Comment: Well, pytest does not do that. What library are you using to test? Please, post the command that calls the tests in your question.

Comment: And include your test file, maybe you're calling some command there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

> This works fine when the application runs (using uvicorn or runserver), but when running tests, the AppConfig.ready() gets executed before the migrations are run.

This is completely true and the reason why the server runs fine is that the `news_newstype` table already exists since the migration that creates the table has already been applied.

However, when running tests, migrations are run before tests are run, and since the table `news_newstype` has not been created in the test database, it results in an error.

### Solution

You should remove your dynamic URL path generated from database values and avoid the code referencing the database table in `NewsConfig.ready()`.

Instead, you may use URL parameter capturing and use the captured value to search against the database in a view method.

Here is `urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path("news/<news_type>/", NewsView.as_view()),
]
```

Then use the captured `news_type` parameter in your view method

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import generics


class NewsView(generics.GenericAPIView)
    def get(self, request, news_type=None):
        # equivalent to NewsType.objects.get(name=news_type)
        # and return response with HTTP 404 status when it's not found
        get_object_or_404(NewType, name=news_type)
        # your code goes here
        ...
```

### Notes

This is just an example with `generics.GenericAPIView`, if you want to use the viewset, please read the restframework documentation.

Also, you may find the docs about URL parameter capturing in the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#example).